# LLVM - setting insert point of BasicBlock after adding instructions causes segfault

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm writing a compiler frontend using LLVM. If I create a `BasicBlock`, add some Instructions to it and finally set the insert point, everything work fine. But when I call `SetInsertPoint` and THEN add some instruction like this:

```
    Function * MainFunction = Function::Create( FT, Function::ExternalLinkage, "main", m_Module );
    BasicBlock * BB = BasicBlock::Create( m_Parser->m_Context, "entry", MainFunction );
    m_Builder.SetInsertPoint( BB );
    CallInst * call = m_Builder.CreateCall( m_Module.getFunction( "writeln" ), {ConstantInt::get( m_Context, APInt( INT_SIZE, 1 ) )}, "calltmp" );
    BB->getInstList().push_back( call );
    m_Builder.CreateRet( ConstantInt::get( Type::getInt32Ty( m_Context ), 0 ) );
```

the program generates LLVM IR correctly, but then at the very end (when calling destructors of LLVM module, context and builder?) it gives segfault. I would really like to do it this way, because then the functions generating the instructions could refer to `BB` as `m_Builder.GetInsertBlock()`. And I can't think of any other way how to implement ifs, nested blocks etc.

Why is it generating code properly and crashing at the end? Is there a small problem or am I missing something and it just can't be done like this?

Comment: I don't use the builder, I build myself, so I cannot answer. But I can comment: Run your code under valgrind, it usually points straight at the source of such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m_Builder.SetInsertPoint( BB );
m_Builder.CreateCall( m_Module.getFunction( "writeln" ), {ConstantInt::get( m_Context, APInt( INT_SIZE, 1 ) )}, "calltmp" );
m_Builder.CreateRet( ConstantInt::get( Type::getInt32Ty( m_Context ), 0 ) );
```

Try this.

Comment: Oh, I think I get how the builder works now. It's this simple. Thank you. Do you think the crash is a bug of LLVM? Or is it just bad usage.

Comment: When an IRBuilder  is used to create an instruction, it will add the created instruction after the specified instruction via setInsertionPoint(). So manually adding it again to the instruction list causes this issue.

Comment: Makes sense, but then I would expect the instruction to be in the block twice. But it's there only once and the generated IR is correct.